# logistic regression/puzzled about scipy.optimize function

Tags: python, scipy, logistic-regression

I was trying to figure out a problem with logistic regression. So the problem is asking to find some parameters to separate points into two groups.
After I completed the costFunction and the gradient function, I decided to use the fmin_tnc function

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import scipy.optimize as opt


    def sigmoid(x):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

    def costFunction(theta,X,y):

        # print(X.shape,theta.shape)

        A=(-y)*np.log(sigmoid(X @ theta))
        # print(A.shape)
        B=(1-y)*np.log(1-sigmoid(X.dot(theta)))
        # print(B.shape)
        return np.mean(A-B)

    data=pd.read_csv("D:\Files\Coursera-ML-AndrewNg-Notes-master\code\ex2-logistic regression\ex2data1.txt",
                     names=['exam1','exam2','admitted'])
    data.insert(0,'Ones',1)
    cols=data.shape[1]
    X=data.iloc[:,0:cols-1]
    y=data.iloc[:,cols-1:cols]
    X=np.array(X.values) #100*3
    y=np.array(y.values) #100*1
    theta=np.zeros(shape=[3,1])


    #X：100*3 y:100*1 theta:3*1
    def gradient(theta,X,y):
        return (X.T @ (sigmoid(X @ theta) - y))/len(X)

theta.reshape([3,1])
res=opt.fmin_tnc(func=costFunction,x0=theta,fprime=gradient,args=(X,y))
    positive = data[data.admitted.isin(['1'])]
    negetive = data[data.admitted.isin(['0'])]
    plt.scatter(positive['exam1'],positive['exam2'],c='r',label='Admitted')
    plt.scatter(negetive['exam1'],negetive['exam2'],c='yellow',marker='x',label='NotAdmitted')

    x1=np.linspace(30,100)
    x2=-1*(final_theta[0]+final_theta[1]*x1)/final_theta[2]

    plt.plot(x1,x2,c='blue')
    plt.savefig('./fig2.png')
    plt.show()
```

the error
[image]

Comment: Where do you call the fmin_tnc function? Where is it coded?

Comment: Sorry I  made some mistakes,now I changed the code.